# django: Retrieve object via backwards relationship in view.py, not template

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, relationship

Just starting out to program in python and I'm having the following issue. I have a template that shows details on a supplier, each supplier has employees and on the template page, I want to show the names of the employees. I know how to do it in the template, but how do you do that in the view?

MODELS:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    co_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    co_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    co_state = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Supplieremployees(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(supplier)
    expe_fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

VIEWS:

```
def supplier_detail(request, supplier_id):
    s = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=supplier_id)
    **test = s.supplieremployees_set.all()**
    return render_to_response('suppliersdb/supplier_detail.html', {'supplier': s})
```

TEMPLATE:

```
...i dont want to use this way, how do i translate this into the view?
{% for supplieremployees in supplier.supplieremployees_set.all %}
    <li>IT Focal: {{ supplieremployees.expe_fname }}</li>
{% endfor %}

**TEST: {{ test.expe_fname }}**
```

**nothing shows up for {{ test.expe_fname }}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def supplier_detail(request, supplier_id):
    s = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=supplier_id)
    for employee in s.supplieremployees_set.all():
        print employee.expe_fname
    return render_to_response('suppliersdb/supplier_detail.html', {'supplier': s})
```

[from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Comment: haha, all the answers touch on an important point of reverse relationships: getting the relation, changing the name of the relation, using the queryset returned by the relation and iterating through it

Comment: i guess what im looking for is the syntax to enter in the view to make this happen without getting an error

Comment: it should work exactly like it does in the template except that you need to make sure you put the set of parenthesis on the end of all - like in the above examples. If that's not working there is something else wrong and you need to post the error

Comment: change `supplier` to `s`. `supplier` doesn't exist

Comment: awesome, well the template shows up but nothing shows up for {{ test.expe_fname }}...

Comment: You need to think about how your view is passing variables to your template and what variables are available. There is no `test` variable in the template as you haven't passed it.

Comment: I see, i wasn't sure of the syntax but i beleive this is what i need:  {'supplier': s, 'test': test})

Comment: last comment: `test` is a queryset of `Supplieremployees`s, not a `Supplieremployees` instance

Answer (score 1):

A `Supplier` object will have a `supplieremployees_set` property that can access the reverse relation:

```
employees = s.supplieremployees_set
```

---

You can also supply a `related_name` argument to the `ForeignKey` and use that:

```
class Supplieremployees(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, related_name='employees')

employees = s.employees
```